# Flash CC wont embed image assets

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap, embed, assets

I have this code on the first frame of the timeline:

```
import flash.display.Bitmap;

[Embed("letter.jpg")]
const Letter:Class;

var letter:Bitmap = new Letter();
addChild(letter);
```

I get this compile time error:

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 1, Column 1 1120: Access of undefined property MainTimeline_Letter.
```

I have tried many ways, but I cant get Flash CC or Flash Builder to compile. The image file is in the same directory. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Here are the source files: [FILES](http://www.intermediatouch.com/dev/graphics_embed_test.zip)

I try it with an MP3, and it works fine...

```
import flash.media.Sound;

[Embed("coffee.mp3")]
var Coffee:Class;

var snd:Sound = new Coffee();
snd.play();
```

Thoughts???

Update:
FYI I am on a Macbook Pro OS X 10.7.5 Using Adobe Flash CC

Answer (score 4):

Finally found the answer! Please go to:

```
/Users/"YOURNAME"/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Flash CC/
```

Delete everything! It should work without the  undefined property error. Worth a try. Good luck!

Comment: +1: Your advice worked for me too.  No problem in CS6.

Comment: Thank you. It happens only on Flash CC on Mac.  SWF embedding too works fine. But only problem with images.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up uninstalling Flash and reinstalling it after dealing with this for 3 days. It worked on on the first run. Thanks Adobe :-(

Update:
Flash CC told me that the my memory was low in the jvm.ini file, but it rendered the embedded image on stage and you can see it. But I changed the value to 512 from 256. I closed Flash, then I reopened it. Thats when I got the compiletime error I've been wrestling with. I changed it back to 256, but then the image doesnt render on the stage (back to square 1). I am going to abandon this method and just load everything as external assets.